# REST Service, POST multi-tiered CSV file, drop wizard, java

Tags: java, rest, csv, dropwizard

I'm wondering if a CSV file loaded through a dropwizard service can have multiple levels.

Example...

```
person,john smith,42 
job,engineer,2012 
job,janitor,2014 
home,new york,2012 
person,bill smith,40 
etc...
```

where one or more sublevels are nested...?

Comment: what I'm looking for is some info on how to implement...point me to an example?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "nested", and "multiple levels". Your example seems like standard csv that breaks on newlines.

Comment: I've broken apart your sample and turned into a single code block to better "represent" the actual CSV input you're talking about. I'm not quite sure what you mean by "multiple levels" but I highly recommend that you work to better explain the problem you're trying to solve.